# Data normalization with preference to a number size

Tags: machine-learning, normalization

I understand that data normalization allows us to take data and place it on a scale of [0,1]. Currently I'm working through a machine learning book and the author talks about normalizing data with preference to smaller or larger numbers.

Is there a formula in general to normalize data like this? As an example, if I want smaller values to be closer to 1 than larger values is there a general formula to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=(x_1,..,x_n)$ then we can define $y = \dfrac{x-min(x)}{max(x-min(x))}$ 
In y all the variables are between 0 and 1.  Now if you want to have all small variables close to one you can define $z = y+1$ or $z = 1/(1-y)$.  Even if I do not understand why you should do something like this

Comment: $z$ would no longer be normalized.  In fact, $y$ would not be normalized, either, in the sense of actually spanning the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Sorry there was an error on $y$.  If you prefer you can define z = 1 - y